# Why a row vector times a matric equals vector component times each row of matric then sum them?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a beginner in linear algebra, when I study [linear algebra tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVKj3LADCnA&list=PL49CF3715CB9EF31D)  at time 22:22,

there give a step:

$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 2 & 7 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b & c\\ 
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i
 \end{bmatrix} = 1*row1 + 2*row 2 + 7 *row3
$

how could him give this step directly, I'm not following him here.

before this step, he only spoke
$
  \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b & c\\ 
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
x & y& z \\ 
 \end{bmatrix} = x*column1 + y*column2 + z*column3
$

and I understand this one, why there skip so fast? I want know more details of the process between these two fomulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write $$\begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b & c\\ 
 d & e & f \\
 g & h & i
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$$

where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the three row vectors. Then the matrix product becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}1& 2 &7\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}=v_1+2\cdot v_2+7\cdot v_3.$$

Hope this answers your question.